# Find the highest non child window in the z order that belongs to my process

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to find the non child window that is highest in the z order that belongs to my process.

I can use EnumWindows to walk the window list, using GetWindowThreadProcessId to mask out windows that belong to other processes; but how do I know where each window is in the z order?

Alternatively, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: This question may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825595/how-to-get-the-zorder-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Once you find one window, use GetWindow() with GW_HWNDFIRST to find the toplevel (non-child) window that's highest in the Z-order.