# What is an alternative to using GetWindow in a loop?

Tags: windows, winapi, z-order

MSDN mentions the following remark for the [`GetWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

> The [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is more reliable than calling `GetWindow`
>   in a loop. An application that calls `GetWindow` to perform this task
>   risks being caught in an infinite loop or referencing a handle to a
>   window that has been destroyed.

Using `EnumChildWindows` works just fine when only interested in listing all windows. However, what if you need the additional z-order functionality which `GetWindow` provides? I can't find all windows ordered by z-order using `EnumChildWindows`.

Does this mean there is no 'safe' way to do so?

Comment: See this accepted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/825619/59303

Comment: @ChrisF `GetNextWindow` is a macro for `GetWindow`.

Comment: Indeed it is. I should have clicked through to the MSDN page.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Z-order, I'd use GetWindow(), but guard against the concerns noted.

If you see a window more than once, stop.  When subsequently referencing a returned window via its handle, be prepared for failure.

Comment: And how to 'be prepared for failure'? Check whether the window isn't destroyed first?

Comment: Sure, that would work - e.g., try GetParent() just to be sure it's real.  It depends on the situation.  If the next API call on that window is in the same piece of code, then you may just want to deal with it in error-handling on whatever that call is.  If the windows you're dealing with aren't really very dynamic (subject to being destroyed or Z-reordered, you can ignore the warning.