# C# : How to get most recently used instance from multiple running instances of my WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process, mru

If there are multipple running applications, I need to get the most recently used. I know that I can find all running instances of my app using Process, but how to find from this list most recently used instance?

Comment: You mean most recently started or most recently used?

Comment: It's your application. Write some usage info to a location that is accessible by all instances?

Answer (score 0):

Use Process.StartTime Property of Process class to know which instance started most recently.

Comment: using StartTime I can find opened most recently, but how can I find used most recently? For example I started instance A, than started instance B, and than continue working on instance A. In this case instance A is most recently used, and instance B is most recently started. And I need to get instance A

Comment: In that case you can use Application.Activated Event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.activated(v=vs.110).aspx) in your app and write some information (like process Id and time-stamp) at a common place. Then read that information in you watcher app to know which process was active recently.

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution using **Z-Order window** [How to get the z-order in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825595/how-to-get-the-z-order-in-windows)