# Retrieve order of open windows as ordered in the Alt-Tab list?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, system.diagnostics

This is the entire code of my C# application, with a simple goal. I want to retrieve the open windows on the system, **ordered by how they were recently opened, just like in the Alt-Tab list.** The Alt-Tab list lists programs as they were last opened, so that pressing Alt-Tab and releasing only once will take you back to the last window you had opened. This code is for Windows 10. The code below does get the information I need, just not in the right order. Where should I look for the information I need?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetOpenWindowName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This information is not available. You have to monitor window activation yourself.

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825595/how-to-get-the-z-order-in-windows

Comment: @PaulF that might be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Related (from 2003) - [What is the Alt+Tab order?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031020-00/?p=42093)

Comment: The [Z-order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#zorder) does not necessarily reflect the activation order. A window with the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` extended window style will break the relationship between Z-order and activation history.

Comment: GetAltTabInfo winapi function. Did you check it? firstly you need to enumerate hwnd of window. And, also check this code: https://github.com/christianrondeau/GoToWindow/blob/e41b822e7254fdc40a40fbbeec251e6ffc1959f8/GoToWindow.Api/WindowsListFactory.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is the best that I was able to do, with the help of **@PaulF, @stuartd,** and **@IInspectible.**

The order of the windows in the Alt-Tab list is roughly the z-order of the windows. **@IInspectible** informs us that a window set to topmost will break this, but for the most part, z-order can be respected. So, we need to get the z-order of open windows.

First, we need to bring in the external function GetWindow, using these two lines:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

Once that function exists, we can create this function to get the z-order:

```
public static int GetZOrder(Process p)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
    var z = 0;
    // 3 is GetWindowType.GW_HWNDPREV
    for (var h = hWnd; h != IntPtr.Zero; h = GetWindow(h, 3)) z++;
    return z;
}
```

Key point: the three in the call to the GetWindow function is a flag:

```
/// <summary>
/// The retrieved handle identifies the window above the specified window in the Z order.
/// <para />
/// If the specified window is a topmost window, the handle identifies a topmost window.
/// If the specified window is a top-level window, the handle identifies a top-level window.
/// If the specified window is a child window, the handle identifies a sibling window.
/// </summary>
GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
```

These are the building blocks to finding the z-order of the windows from a process list, which is (for the most part) what the Alt-Tab order is.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing EnumWindows seems to return the windows in tab order

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);
```

Here is a good explanation of how to use
[How can I use EnumWindows to find windows with a specific caption/title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402/how-can-i-use-enumwindows-to-find-windows-with-a-specific-caption-title)